# How to set proxy via SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy

I has a machine named A(doesn't have private IP) in my LAN, and I want to connect the machine A via SSH, but my host is not in the LAN. I have a machine B(it has private IP), I want to set the machine B as the proxy machine so that I can connect the machine A from my localhost via the machine B(proxy machine) anywhere.

How can I make it by using SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `autossh` is very helpful,

In machine A, type the following commands to create reverse connection

```
$ autossh -f -N -R port_num:localhost:22 username@proxy_machine
```

Now, you can connect machine A anywhere

```
$ ssh -t username@proxy_machine "ssh user@machine_A -p 38935"
```